# Animate ecg pulse line builded with border and border-radius

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, keyframe

I've got follow code:

```css
.cWrapper {
  display: flex;
}
.cLine {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.cLine1 {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: transparent gray gray transparent;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
}
.cLine2 {
  width: 20px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: gray gray transparent transparent;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
}
.cLine3 {
  width: 20px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: transparent gray gray transparent;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
  align-self: flex-end;
}
.cLine4 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: transparent transparent gray transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="cWrapper">
  <canvas class="cLine cLine1"></canvas>
  <canvas class="cLine cLine2"></canvas>
  <canvas class="cLine cLine3"></canvas>
  <canvas class="cLine cLine4"></canvas>
</div>
```

I tried to build a ecg pulse line with `border` and `border-radius`. This worked easy for me (I have to style it a little bit bether, but for the moment it's good for me). So the next stem is to animate this lines and make a ecg pulse line like in this example:

[image]

At the moment I don't have an idea, how to do this. I tried it with `jquery` and `animate()` and also with `css3` `keyframes`, but nothing worked. Has someone an idea how to do this? Thanks.

Comment: I suggest to make in JS script which will move the div with canvas, and make another black div, on half of the screen which will be static and ll cover the right half of the screen

Comment: @MaciejWójcik So you are making an example with this idea? Or is it just a suggest for me to try it by myself? Cheers

Comment: I can make some example but later. Now It is only idea.  Write me if u can't make it, then I try to make example

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @MaciejWójcik Please look at my own answer, I solved it like that.

Comment: @Paulie_D Please look at my own answer, I solved it like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I develop software solutions for the health care and I needed an own loading indicator, when I have to wait for any data etc. So I decided to make a ecg pulse line animation to stay at the topic of the software. After that I saw the loading indicator of `windows 8` which works like this one:

[image]

After that I had the idea, to work also with such an animation (little circles following each), because this are known standards on modern web solutions. So I tried to make also little circles following each other, but in form of an ecg pulse line. It worke fine and looks pretty nice. I used `css3 keyframes`. Now it looks like this:

```css
.cWrapper {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: transparent;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
.cPoint {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 50px;
  -webkit-animation-name: pulse;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2.0s;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-name: pulse;
  animation-duration: 2.0s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
.p1 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-delay: 0s;
}
.p2 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.2s;
  animation-delay: 0.2s;
}
.p3 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.4s;
  animation-delay: 0.4s;
}
.p4 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.6s;
  animation-delay: 0.6s;
}
.p5 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.8s;
  animation-delay: 0.8s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
  0%: {
    left: 0px;
    top: 50px;
  }
  30% {
    left: 50px;
    top: 50px;
  }
  40% {
    left: 70px;
    top: 0px;
  }
  60% {
    left: 90px;
    top: 100px
  }
  70% {
    left: 110px;
    top: 50px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 160px;
    top: 50px;
  }
}
@keyframes pulse {
  0%: {
    left: 0px;
    top: 50px;
  }
  30% {
    left: 50px;
    top: 50px;
  }
  40% {
    left: 70px;
    top: 0px;
  }
  60% {
    left: 90px;
    top: 100px
  }
  70% {
    left: 110px;
    top: 50px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 160px;
    top: 50px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="cWrapper">
  <div class="cPoint p1"></div>
  <div class="cPoint p2"></div>
  <div class="cPoint p3"></div>
  <div class="cPoint p4"></div>
  <div class="cPoint p5"></div>
</div>
```

So this solved my requirement. Thanks.

Comment: great! you solved your question yourself. worth an upvote.

Comment: @LearnHowToBeTransparent Yes it's great, thanks! Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most convenient way to solve the problem is to use a canvas wrapped in a web component. Check up source code in [this](https://github.com/tripolskypetr/ecg-line-webcomponent) github repository

```
document.body.innerHTML += '<ecg-line></ecg-line>';
ecgLine((bang) => setInterval(() => bang(), 1000));
```

[image]